# get undefined result when testing composable using fetch

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

There is a composable using `fetch` to retrive data:

```js
export const useFetchData = (q?: string) => {
  const data: Ref<Data | undefined> = ref();
  const error: Ref<Error | undefined> = ref();
  const isLoading = ref(true);

  const fetchData = async (q?: string) => {
    if (!q)
      return
    isLoading.value = true;
    fetch(`https://url/q=${q}`)
      .then(r => r.json().then(d => {
        data.value = d
      }))
      .catch(err => error.value = err)
      .finally(() => {isLoading.value = false});
  }

  fetchData(location, langCode);

  return { data, error, isLoading };

}
```

When testing it, I used the following code:

```js
const testData = {data: 'value'};

global.fetch = vi.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
        json: () => Promise.resolve(testData),
        ok: true,
      })) as any;

const { data, error, isLoading } = useFetchData('test');

    expect(error.value).toBeUndefined;
    expect(isLoading.value).toBeFalsy;
    expect(data.value).toBe(testData) //failed!;
```

The last assertion failed due to the `data.value` is `undefined`. However, the same code ( as testing) works correctly in components.

May I know how make it works in tests please?

Comment: You need `flush-promises` or similar

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your current test:

1. you need to flush promises before asserting the `expect`, using [`flush-promises`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flush-promises), as pointed out in comments by @EstusFlask.
2. [`toBe()`](https://vitest.dev/api/expect.html#tobe) does not assert object equality, it asserts object identity. Use [`toEqual()`](https://vitest.dev/api/expect.html#toequal) for objects.

> `toBe` can be used to assert if ***primitives* are equal** or that objects share the same reference.

In codespeak:

```
const a = { foo: 'bar' }
const b = { foo: 'bar' }
const c = a

expect(a).toBe(a)     // PASS
expect(a).toBe(b)     // FAIL
expect(a).toBe(c)     // PASS
expect(a).toEqual(b)  // PASS
expect(a).not.toBe(b) // PASS

c.foo = 'baz'
expect(a.foo).toBe('baz') // PASS
/* 
 * When you change `c` you change `a`,
 * and when you change `a` you change `c`,
 * because they reference the same object.
 * That's what `toBe()` checks when used with objects.
 */
```

Comment: This is a problem here because vue proxy !== original object, but this won't solve the one with race condition

Comment: @Estus, you're right, for the test to pass promises must be flushed, using `flush-promises`. I'll add it to the answer.